# Write a program to elaborate the concept of function overloading using pointers as a function arguments?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, overloading

I know what overloaded functions are but I don’t know how to elaborate it using pointers. If someone can give me a basic program to elaborate function overloading using pointer as a function argument.

Comment: why do you think pointers would be special with regard to function overloading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments stated, it's not entirely clear where your problem is. It would be nice if you included an example for what you want to understand better, anyway, here's an example:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(int x) {
  std::cout << x << std::endl; 
}

void foo(int* x) {
  std::cout << (*x + 1) << std::endl; 
}

int main() {
  int x = 4;

  foo(x); // prints 4
  foo(&x); // prints 5
  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank You !  My Problem Was I couldnt Figure out how to Overload Pointers now i get it u used Address to Overload it .